# Worklight 5.0.6 : Ajax request exception: Form too large while sending large data to data adapter

Tags: ajax, exception, request, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

My question is relatively the same than the one posted on developerworks forum (forum is read only due to migration) wich is :

> I have a http adapter that interfaces with external web services. Part
>   of the payload is audio, and images. We're hitting a form size limit.
>   Please see attached exception at end of this post. I've read on
>   previous posts that jetty configurations need to be adjusted to
>   accommodate the larger payload. We want to control this size limit at
>   the server side application layer, and thought that of creating a
>   jetty-web.xml to define the max form size:
>
> 400000
>
> In Worklight is this the proper approach to resolve this issue?
>
> If this is the proper approach can you provide details whether the
>   jetty-web.xml should be placed under server/conf, or does it need to
>   be under WEB-INF of the application war?
>
> If the file needs to be placed under WEB-INF can you explain how to
>   accomplish this file being placed under WEB-INF during the WL project
>   build.
>
> Thanks E: Ajax request exception: Form too large802600>200000
>   2013-02-06 11:39:48 FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description:
>   INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred
>   during gadget request Form too large802600>200000, User Identity
>   {wl_authenticityRealm=null, GersServiceAdapterRealm=(name:USAEMP4,
>   loginModule:GersServiceAdapterLoginModule),
>   wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:NullLoginModule,
>   loginModule:NullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=null,
>   wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:antiXSRF, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule),
>   wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null,
>   wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:device,
>   loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule),
>   myserver=(name:3e857b6a-d2f6-40d1-8c9c-10ca1b96c8df,
>   loginModule:WeakDummy),
>   wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:3e857b6a-d2f6-40d1-8c9c-10ca1b96c8df,
>   loginModule:WeakDummy)}.

I have exactly the same problem : 
I send a large amount of data to a worklight adapter and my application fail with the following error message into the log :

```
2013-08-21 09:48:17] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: Form too large202534>200000
[2013-08-21 09:48:18] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request Form too large202534>200000, User Identity {wl_authenticityRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=(name:null, loginModule:NullLoginModule), SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=(name:b2isf3704k2fl8hovpa6lv9mig, loginModule:WLAntiXSRFLoginModule), wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=(name:40a24da9-0a32-464a-8dec-2ab402c683ae, loginModule:WLDeviceNoProvisioningLoginModule), myserver=(name:2b1a7864-37c4-47f0-9f5c-49621b6915b5, loginModule:WeakDummy), wl_anonymousUserRealm=(name:2b1a7864-37c4-47f0-9f5c-49621b6915b5, loginModule:WeakDummy)}.
```

This occurs on calling an adapter procedure by calling WL.Client.invokeProcedure(...) and before the first line of the called procedure... If I try to log the start of the called procedure I have nothing written in my debug log...

I can give you my source code :

This one is called by a dhtml user event (onclick) :

```
// Construct the param to pass to the WL adapter insert procedure
var paramObject = {
    QCDART: machine,                    // machine is a javascript variable as long int
    QTITRE: title,                      // title is a javascript variable as string(255)
    QDESC: desc,                        // desc is a javascript variable as string(255)
    QHODAT: todayDateDb2IntFormat,      // todayDateDb2IntFormat is a javascript variable as long int
    QACTIF: active,                     // active is a javascript variable as int
    SSRCFIC: currentPdfFileDataBase64,  // currentPdfFileDataBase64 is a javascript variable as base64 encoded string from a binary file > 150 ko approx.
    SMIMFIC: 'application/pdf',         
    SSIZFIC: currentPdfFileSize         // currentPdfFileSize is a javascript variable as long int
};

// Construct adapter invocation data
var invocationData = {
    adapter : 'IseriesDB2Backend', // adapter name
    procedure : 'addModeleReleves', // procedure name
    parameters : [paramObject] // parameters if any
};

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    timeout: 60000,
    onSuccess: function() {
        // Notify success
        alert('OK');
    }, // invokeProcedure success callback
    onFailure: function(invocationResult) {
        alert('ERROR');
    } // invokeProcedure failure callback
});
```

This one is my adapter source code :

```
var addModeleReleveStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("select QCDDOC from FINAL TABLE (insert into ERIHACFICH.DOCENTQ (QCDART, QTITRE, QDESC, QHODAT, QACTIF) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?))");
function addModeleReleves(params) {
    WL.Logger.debug('Starting adapter procedure...');

    var modeleReleveResult =  WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : addModeleReleveStatement,
        parameters : [params.QCDART, params.QTITRE, params.QDESC, params.QHODAT, params.QACTIF]
    });

    if(modeleReleveResult.isSuccessful) {
        WL.Logger.debug('Success !');
    }

    WL.Logger.debug('Adapter procedure ended !');

    // Return result (with the last id inside)
    return modeleReleveResult;
}
```

if the javascript varable called currentPdfFileDataBase64 is small, all is working normally but if it exceeds approximatively 200000 chars length it fails...

Last, I ca say that the problem occurs in development environment (WL Studio 5.0.6 + WL Server 5.0.6), I didn't test it on the production environment based on SLES + Websphere application server 7 + worklight.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try adapters?

Comment: Yes I use an sql adapter generated by WLStudio wizards

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are using the test server provided by Worklight.

It looks like this is a Jetty limitation so you could try any of these:

1) Set the system property org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize to a bigger value (i.e. adding -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize=25000000) to the end of eclipse.ini before launching Worklight.

or

2) Instead, set this other system property -Dorg.mortbay.jetty.Request.maxFormContentSize=25000000 to the same place.

Comment: I forgot to mention, but this is server side configuration, so different configuration may apply for the production server (since it won't be Jetty)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for your information you were right when you said it's different in production becaus this problem doesn't occurs under WAS 7 + WL5.06 in production

Comment: Would you mind setting your question as answered then? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the problem was to use WL Studio version  6 that doesn't use Jetty anymore as test environment